which one is correct, "looking forward to hear" OR "looking forward to hearing"
From my understanding, 'to' is not followed by 'continuous form'. So the latter version "looking forward to hearing" looks incorrect to me.
However, when I type that in gmail, it first auto complete to "looking forward to hear from you", and then it shows suggestion to correct it to "looking forward to hearing from you"
What am I missing here?

The gerund-participial (ing) clause is correct

The verb has bearing on which form to use.  For example, we say "hoping to see you at the party" but "looking forward to seeing you at the party".   hoping {marked  form of the verb} {something} and looking forward to {something} and {something} can be satisfied with the gerund-participle form.

You look forward to A NOUN (for example, "I'm looking forward to Christmas"), so if you're going to use a verb-based object, it has to be a gerund / participial -ing-based form.

OALD, Cambridge Dictionary etc clearly has the construction as 'look forward to', followed by a noun or an ing-form.


I'm looking forward [to hearing from you].

is the correct version.
Prepositions like "to" mostly take noun phrases as object, but a gerund-participial (ing) clause is not a noun.
However, gerund-participials are more like NPs than infinitivals, which is seen in the fact that they can invert with the subject in interrogatives, and this greater likeness to NPs is reflected in their being more readily able to function as complement of a preposition.

Looking forward to hearing from you is correct, but the analysis is not, or at least it is unhelpful.  It is better analyzed as I'm looking forward to [hearing from you].  The brackets identify the object of the preposition, which could be any sort of noun phrase.  A gerundive is a noun (while a present participle is not).  As such, it can be a subject or the object of a verb, etc.  Seeing is believing.  I like playing piano.  Reading makes me tired.  Etc.

@phoog, I’d offer yet a third analysis: look forward to is a phrasal verb that licenses a nioun-phrase complement: I look forward to our vacation and I look forward to it.   So neither forward nor to is acting as a preposition any more than the up does in After years of failing to learn to ride a unicycle, I gave up.

@PaulTanenbaum The whole expression "to look forward to sth" is considered to be an idiom in OALD; "sth" can be a NP or an -ing form. Accordingly, the  parsing of "forward" and "to" as prepositions is not possible.

@phoog "Hearing from you" is a clause, not an NP, so it can't be object of "to", though it it is complement. Note that clauses are not NPs. "To hearing from you" is a preposition phrase with the prep "to" as head and the gerund-participial clause as its complement. Note that not everything that functions as complement of a prep is an NP.

@PaulTanenbaum "Hearing from you" is not a noun phrase, but a gerund-participial clause functioning as complement of the preposition "to". Just because it is replaceable by an appropriate NP, doesn't mean it's NP -- it isn't. It matters not how we analyse "look forward to". The fact is "to" is a preposition with a gerund-participial clause as its complement.

@LPH Of course it's an idiom, but that doesn't mean it can't be analysed. It consists of a verb + a preposition with no complement + a preposition with a complement (here, a clause). And what relevance does your comment have to the OP's question?  You need to stop posting comments that have no substance.

@BillJ That is the essence of idioms: the usual relations expressed by the grammatical words do not hold; the words can be vaguely identified as grammatical words, but no particular relation that is listed for them in a dictionary can be chosen as a relation that could be applicable in the idiom; therefore there is no possible real analysis. What meaning of "to" can you extract from a dictionary that will be applicable in "look forward to"? None I believe.

@phoog My answer was not intended to suggest an analysis, but simply to show the correct constituent functioning as complement of "forward", i.e. the PP "to hearing from you", as opposed to the incorrect infinitival "to hear from you". Hearing from you" is not an NP but a gerund-participial clause functioning as complement - not NP object - of "to". Note that preps take a range of complement types comparable to that of verbs, not just object NPs, but predicatives, PPs, AdvPs and clauses. We obviously don't want to call them all nouns.

@LPH Do not lecture native English speakers, especially teachers, who know a lot more than you do. Now take that on board: You are talking about the semantic interpretation of the idiom "look forward to". What you say about the analysis is wrong. All idioms can be analysed. In this case the idiom consists of a verb + a preposition with no complement + a preposition with a complement (here, a clause).

@BillJ I see in your "explanations" only broad  allegations without references.

@LPH What do you mean by "broad allegations". That makes no sense. This is simple basic grammar. If you can't understand it, you shouldn't be posting negative comments.

@BillJ  No, idioms cannot be analysed: "an expression in the usage of a language that is peculiar to itself either in having a meaning that cannot be derived from the conjoined meanings of its elements (such as up in the air for "undecided") or in its grammatically atypical use of words (such as 'give way')" (Merriam-Webster). There is only way in which you can speak of analysing them: that is when you classify them into pure or partial idioms, and so on. You do not mean "analysis" in that way; you seem to pretend that "analyzing" means to produce a meaning from the words. This is wrong.

@LPH That is absolute nonsense. Of course idioms can be syntactically analysed. I never said anything about meaning, but only syntax. I'm not pretending anything but stating quite clearly that the idiom  "look forward to" is analysed as verb + a preposition with no complement + a preposition with a complement. Text-book stuff.

@BillJ I believe that you present us here with a third meaning for "analysing", and that it is really an otiose concept: what is a relational word to which no relation can be attributed with certitude? Of course, in many cases, although I am not sure that it is true in all cases, it will be possible to say what part of speech we are dealing with, but what is the good of that? It is of little interest as far as I know. What interest do you see in that? Words with no real meaning… They constitute mostly an abstract code that has to be added to the natural code of definitions of words.

@LPH  Where did you read that nonsense.  It's a simple grammatical analysis of the words and phrases involved. You say it can't be analysed, and I say it can be, as I've just demonstrated. It was you who said it can't be analysed and I've just proved it can. It's of interest to those studying English grammar, in particular diagramming.

@LPH It's of interest to those studying English grammar, in particular diagramming.

@LPH I see you are suspended from chatting on this site! I'm not surprised.

The confusion arises because to is an infinitive marker in English.  It has that function, for example, in the phrase mentioned in the comments, hoping to... (hoping to see you, hoping to hear from you, etc.).
But to in look forward to is just a garden-variety preposition, as is at in the phrase looking back at.  As a preposition, it should be followed by a noun phrase:

I'm looking forward to his return
I'm looking forward to the next installment
I'm looking forward to your response

As you probably know, a noun phrase may be a gerundive, i.e., the nominalized -ing form of the verb, as in playing piano is relaxing, where the subject is playing piano.

I'm looking forward to seeing him again
I'm looking forward to reading the next installment
I'm looking forward to hearing from you


"Hearing from you" is not an NP but a gerund-participial clause functioning as complement - not NP object - of "to". Note that preps take a range of complement types comparable to that of verbs, not just object NPs, but predicatives, PPs, AdvPs and clauses. We obviously don't want to call them all nouns. In your last three examples, the gerund-participials are all clauses, the last one being the OP's example.

A search in Google Books shows that in comparison "looking forward to hearing" is vastly more frequent; however an examination of the hits for "looking forward to hear" shows that numerous false positives make up the collections. In conclusion, it can be said that the curve for "looking forward to hear" is not representative of a usage and that it should be comparatively near zero.
looking forward to hearing
looking forward to hear

The only idiomatic turn is really "looking forward to hearing".

We all know that the gerund-participial (ing) clause is correct. But you've made no attempt to say why it is.
